# Keycloak: Making custom UserModel implementation work for OIDC

Tags: java, openid-connect, keycloak

### What I want to do:

Make Keycloak work as authentication provider using OIDC, for users provided by a custom User Storage SPI implementation.

### What I have done so far:

- Setup Keycloak 8.0.1 (realm, client, "native" test users, etc.)
- Setup a small Spring Boot App (Spring Security without the Keycloak Adapter) as test client
- Implement and install a custom User Storage SPI, following this guide https://www.keycloak.org/docs/8.0/server_development/#simple-read-only-lookup-example
  I took small liberties to keep it more extendable (for example, creating an actual class for the UserModel), but that shouldn't influence the functional bits.

### What works:

- Authentication (Authorization Grant Flow) in the client app for "native" Keycloak users

### What doesn't work:

- Authentication in the client app for users provided through the User Storage SPI

From what I can tell, the failure occurs when the access token is created. Login, code creation and redirect happen.

I assume the problem is that my UserModel implementation does not provide all needed attributes to create a token. Could be something different...

Here is what it looks like:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.keycloak.component.ComponentModel;
import org.keycloak.models.ClientModel;
import org.keycloak.models.GroupModel;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession;
import org.keycloak.models.RealmModel;
import org.keycloak.models.RoleModel;
import org.keycloak.storage.adapter.AbstractUserAdapter;

import de.dfb.keycloak.spi.userstorage.service.DfbUserDto;

public class DfbUser extends AbstractUserAdapter {

    private String username;

    public DfbUser(KeycloakSession session, RealmModel realm, ComponentModel storageProviderModel, DfbUserDto userDto) {
        super(session, realm, storageProviderModel);

        this.username = userDto.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    // TODO Only implemented to avoid this problem
    // https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-6115
    @Override
    public void setSingleAttribute(String name, String value) {
        if (!name.equals(LOCALE)) {
            super.setSingleAttribute(name, value);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

### What I want to know:

1. How do I make this work? If it's just missing user attributes: Which ones am I missing? What should they look like?
2. Are there more resources available, to get a better grasp of keycloaks data model, to avoid similar problems? The developer docs do not seem quite extensive enough and the java doc is missing a bunch of commentary.